# How long should it take to generate a view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an app with Rails and the the `rails server` command, I see how long it takes to generate a view.

I collected a sample from the output of the same page.

```
Completed 200 OK in 935ms (Views: 934.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1093ms (Views: 1093.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 907ms (Views: 907.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 970ms (Views: 969.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 901ms (Views: 900.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1003ms (Views: 1002.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1069ms (Views: 1069.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 991ms (Views: 991.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 933ms (Views: 933.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 933ms (Views: 932.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 54.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 993ms (Views: 992.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1077ms (Views: 1076.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 52.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 54.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 988ms (Views: 988.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 908ms (Views: 907.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 899ms (Views: 899.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 872ms (Views: 871.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 54.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 59.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 55.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 57.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1178ms (Views: 1178.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 998ms (Views: 998.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 116.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 34.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 33.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 29.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 23.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 22.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 55.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 54.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 996ms (Views: 996.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1091ms (Views: 1091.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 75.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 68.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 68.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 126.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 940ms (Views: 939.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 33.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 982ms (Views: 981.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 930ms (Views: 929.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 73.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1075ms (Views: 1075.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 34.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 121ms (Views: 120.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 35.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Note the request are from same page. It ranges from 35ms to 1000ms. Looking into the details, I only see how it renders the partial

```
  Rendered svgs/_logo_typeface_blue_small.html (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_header_nav.html.slim (1.0ms)
  Rendered templates/_calendar.html (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/item.html.slim within layouts/application (10.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash.html.slim (0.1ms)
```

Which shouldn't cause the 900ms View generation time. I wonder how I can understand more about what cause the 1000ms view generation

Comment: beware of those stats. Actually activerecord queries are lazy loaded, so the time spent in db queries is added to the view rendering since its usually done there. I guess you have N+1 issues or alike

Comment: Hmm, the views are not linked to any database query at the moment.

Comment: you have no instance variables? no ruby code?

Comment: since i am building the frontend first before implementing the database. I would say the only model i have now is user, minimal setup from Devise.

Comment: But I do have some AJAX call from APIs like Google map

Comment: The way I usually deal with this is I put a raise somewhere in the view. If it still takes a long time to render, I move it up. Usually there will be a single line responsible for a slow rendering. Unfortunately I am not able to help you any further without seeing the code.

Comment: Also note that in development rails are rebuilding assets when they changed, which might take a while as well.